# Qt under linux, how to detect a process is already running?

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I am developing under ubuntu 16.04.
The issue I run into is: I want to detect whether the user has already started the application, if yes, it exits directly.

I have tried using `QLocalServer`, `QSharedMemory` to achieve that.
But the problem is:

If the program ***crash without properly close the local server or destroy the shared memory***, the ***local socket/shared memory*** will ***remain in the OS*** and prevent the user to launch the program again.

How to deal with this?

Comment: Your OS should be closing resources when your process dies, I suspect it just didn't completely die and is still in memory. Typically this is done by opening a specific file for writing, because only 1 process can do that at a time.

Comment: But it seems this is common phenomenon for Qt under Linux... Just wonder is there any workaround?

Comment: In what way is the file workaround insufficient?

Comment: @nwp, I have tried using QFile to open a file for writing. But its seems under linux, two process can write to the same file though?

Comment: @nwp The thing with opening a file for writing is not true in linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the shared memory issue you could take a look at this question [QSharedMemory is not getting deleted on Application crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42549904/qsharedmemory-is-not-getting-deleted-on-application-crash/42551052#42551052)

For a more generic answer about having a single instance of an application, you can take a look at [Qt Single Application](https://github.com/qtproject/qt-solutions/tree/master/qtsingleapplication) which is part of [qt-solutions](https://github.com/qtproject/qt-solutions)